# How to pull images out of WordPress content?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to 'pull' the images out of the content of my WordPress posts. I put them in the content in the admin panel with the text. When output, they are wrapped in `<p>` tags. I want to pull them out so I can wrap them in my own custom tags (so I can CSS them and `<p>` independently).

I have the following code that pulls out the block quote, not sure how to rewrite it to pull out the images.

```
<div class="block-pull">
    <?php
        // get the content
        $content = get_the_content();

        // check and retrieve blockquote
        if(preg_match('~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~', $content, $matches))

        // output blockquote
        echo $matches[1];
    ?>
</div>
```

I want to put the images in a different spot on my page, and the text somewhere else. I am currently bringing them in with:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Comment: just goto admin edit page option and in visual edtor move to text editor and wrap your images around <div><img></div> and even you can put an id or class here than you will not see <p> tags

Comment: it doesn't seem to 'save' when i do that. They go back to just having < p > tags

Comment: in text mode of editor first you have to move your image outside of the <p> tag than put a div tag arround it i have just managed to this in my practice but don't move to visual tab before doing update.

Comment: oh ok, I don't see it in any tags in the editor though, I just look at the output in the browser inspector

Comment: if you don't see any tags even than you have to put <div></div> around the image because if there is no tag around any tag than default tag is <p> in visual Editor or after you update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get and display only the images from the content:

```
preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
for($i=0; isset($images[1]) && $i < count($images[1]); $i++) {
    echo $images[1][$i];
}
```

To display the content without any images.

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<img [^>]*>)/', '', get_the_content());
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
echo $content;
```

Comment: I'm a bit of a noobie when it comes to coding, where does this code put the images. How can I put them back in the page, but put somewhere else (in a div/etc)

Comment: Follow up question, If i understand correctly I put this code in replacement of the get_content() command. SO I would need one to pull out the text to i would guess?

Comment: @user3550879 yes, and try this `echo preg_replace('/(<img [^>]*>)/', '', get_the_content());` also added it into the answer.

Comment: Sorry to bug, is there a way to wrap the text when its pulled out, checked my browser inspector and its just text not wrapped in any tags at all. It does show a link to the image as well, but doesn't show it

Comment: that works much better, the text is now in <p> tags. the code that pulls the text still pulls the <href> link though and puts it in the code, but doesn't show it on the page. I guess thats how its supposed to work

Comment: @user3550879 I have not figured out on getting rid of the image link, you'll have to remove it from the admin panel post editor if necessary. Otherwise open another question, see if anyone knows.